# postgraphile - function to add structured data as field on mutation

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgraphile

I'd like to do the simplest possible thing to add structured data to a postgraphile mutation.

I have a simple example table:

```
> \d test1.my_table                                                                                                                                                                      
+----------+--------+
| Column   | Type   |
|----------+--------+
| id       | uuid   |
| the_box  | box    |
+----------+--------+
```

The `box` column creates a type of `{kind: "SCALAR", name: "String", ofType: null}` through postgraphile, which leaves me to parse the result of a query, and marshal the data into a string for a mutation.

```
query MyQuery {
  myTables {
    nodes { id theBox }
  }
}
```

yields

```
{
  "data": {
    "myTables": {
      "nodes": [
        {
          "id": "c79ee287-88ca-4950-a44b-e4ef07d3c3dc",
          "theBox": "(3,4),(1,2)"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

A similar thing happens for `polygon` or `bytea` types.

In my ideal world, I write a [computed column](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/computed-columns/) function for the query which returns the `box` (or `polygon`, or `bytea`) as some custom postgres type.

```
CREATE TYPE box_arg AS (x point, y point);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test1.my_table_box_for_query(the_row test1.my_table)  
RETURNS box_arg AS $$  
BEGIN 
   SELECT '(the_row.the_box[0][0], the_row.the_box[1][0])'::point,
          '(the_row.the_box[0][1], the_row.the_box[1][1])'::point;
END; 
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' STABLE;
```

(Leaving aside whether i'm picking the right x/y in that query...)

However, I can't seem to figure out the other direction. How do I write a function that is exposed on the mutation created by postgraphile for `my_table` that will accept structured data (the `box_arg` type from above, for example), and have the function update the record during the mutation with the values from the function argument? I'd like to have the `box_arg` type as an input on the mutation. Indeed, you can see here that the box is only available on the `input` as a string.

[image: Example of theBox parameter as a string]

Is this possible with a postgres function? Or is this only possible via a postgraphile plugin?

Thank you so much for any advice/examples!

Comment: Pretty sure there is a simple solution. But I don't see the clear question. What is the function supposed to do exactly? (Don't assume we know anything about Postgraphile, most of us don't.)

Comment: Sorry - I guess you do need to know a little bit about postgraphile for the question to make much sense. Postgraphile introspects your postgres db, and automatically builds out a graphql server. If you name postgres functions a certain way, it will automatically add graphql interface affordances. I'm looking for the magic postgres function that creates a `box_arg` type data structure for my auto-generated mutation.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't know what you are asking. I have tried ...

Comment: Thank you for looking, Erwin, it's appreciated. I think the problem was that this was a question specifically about the postgraphile application (which is tightly tied to postgres, hence the postgres tag). My apologies, and thanks again!